# Trying to add a table with SQL, getting "invalid identifier" error with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

This is a block of code that SHOULD create a new table (vehicles) with the primary key being 'VNo' and the foreign key being 'did'.

```
create table vehicles
(VNo integer,
model varchar(20),
year integer,
constraint vehicles_VNo_pk primary key (VNo),
constraint vehicles_did_fk foreign key (did) references division(did)
);
```

however, running this code yields a:

```
ORA-00904: "DID": invalid identifier
```

error, no matter what I do. Please help! This is for an important assignment.

Comment: There is no column `DID` on the table `vehicles`. So how can you create a Foreign Key without the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `did` field in your table creation statement for `vehicles`:

```
create table vehicles
(VNo integer,
model varchar(20),
year integer,
did column_type,
constraint vehicles_VNo_pk primary key (VNo),
constraint vehicles_did_fk foreign key (did) references division(did)
);
```

replacing `column_type` with whatever type `did` should be.